# How to avoid "Hack" on Parse current user file on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm developing a Social/Messaging app for Android on Android Studio using Parse as the backend.
I think I could have a problem with security, because the app let you buy a premium account using your credit card or coins that you get watching ads, in the activity where you update your profile the app saves the new data (from editText) using `ParseUser.getCurrentUser.saveInBackground`. Root users could modify the currentUserFile and then when the app updates the data, the modified data get updated
My question: does Parse only updates the new data or updates the whole user Object using `saveInBackground` ?
Is there a way to only update single data as age, gender, etc?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Problem solved, see comments below

Comment: Good question, I have never tried this myself but why don't you try and do it? When you make changes locally to a Parse User/Object in your app, nothing is saved until the saved operation is passed over the network, and uploaded on Parse's cloud. I think if the data is different on the cloud than locally there could be an issue, and might override local changes.

Comment: Generally speaking, don't worry about people who have rooted their phones, they have purposefully broken the security model in Android and there is nothing you can do to make it secure again. Make sure your backend doesn't give out information about other users or let you enable features the user hasn't paid for.

Comment: Problem solved! Parse only updates the new data without updating the non-updated from the currentUser file
e.g: If you modify your age from 21 yr old to 22, and you have a rooted phone and modified your coins from 100 o 99999,Parse only updates the age, unless you decide to update the coins